# CSS Background color of a textbox to be applied only to text

Tags: css, colors, background, textbox

I have two text boxes overlapping one another. The first text box, 'TextBox1', is defined by user input. The second, 'TextBox2', is populated by an AutoComplete functionality. My goal is to have the background of the first text box to be white ONLY for the text that has been typed so that the resulting 'TextBox2' only displays the remainder of the account name that gets returned.

Example: User types "ut tr" and the AutoComplete that gets stored in 'TextBox2' becomes:
 "UT Training". I have a text transform to capitalize the first letter of each word so after the transform (as the user types) "Ut Tr".

When the input is overlapped with the results that are in 'TextBox2' the two do no match because of the difference in the case of the letter. This can cause major cosmetic problems in other examples.

So, if the background of the text for the input textbox, 'TextBox1', could be white, then the user would only see what they've typed, and the remainder of the Autocomplete.

Thanks for any help! This is my first post so I apologize if I've unknowingly done anthing taboo.

Here is a link to a video that shows how this looks: http://screencast.com/t/ef6dBJyU2X14

Comment: This is an interesting approach to autocompleting... I personally feel that it is a little prone to bugginess, but upvoted for cool idea.

Comment: It's a little un-clear to me what your question is.

Comment: From what I've found, the background-color attribute for CSS is applied to the whole of the element. I did stumble upon making a span within the element have a background color, but I am not sure how to do this within a text box, or if this is sufficient to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check how many characters are now inputted by user, by something similar to:

```
$('#myInput').on('keydown', function() {
    inputLength = $(this).val().length
});
```

​And after that change color of the first `N = inputLength` characters in your auto complete to white. Probably, using substring:

```
substring(0, inputLength);
```

Comment: I am fairly certain that this would apply a background color for the whole width of the textbox, thus covering up 'TextBox2'. Currently the background color for both text boxes are transparent so that when the text is overlapped, both are visible. 'TextBox1's text is black so it appears, to the user, to be on top of 'TextBox2', which has green text.

Comment: Looks like you have unreasonably complicated structure. Could you tell clearly, what exactly you want to achieve, then it will be possible to propose solutions.

Comment: Here is a video of what it looks like so far: [link](http://screencast.com/t/ef6dBJyU2X14) right now the text-transform:capitalize takes care of most problems, but not all of them. I'd like for the user input to not change when they type something in, which is why I am pursuing my question

Comment: It looks like this is the most plausible way to solve my problem. I tried a method almost identical to what you have suggested and I think its the best way to do it, it just got ugly fast so I pursued CSS and it almost worked! Thanks for your help, I'll mark this as answered

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to your input and apply a CSS styling for that like;

```
.someclass{
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
<input type="text" class="someclass">
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/svPPp/)*** is a working Live Demo.